# $N$ general points and family of curves forming a linear system of dimension $\geq N$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-surfaces

Let $N \in \mathbf{Z}$. Suppose $S$ be a projective surface and $C \subset S$ be a curve on $S$. Assume that the linear system $|C|$ has dimension $\geq N$. Suppose we are given $N$ general points on $S$. I have seen in papers assertions of the kind that one can find a (nonsingular) curve $C' \in |C|$ such that all the $N$ points lie on $C'$.

To give an example, consider the following paper of Hartshorne: [Some examples of Gorenstein liaison in codimension 3.](http://www.raco.cat/index.php/CollectaneaMathematica/article/viewFile/56527/66215) Look at 5th page, last paragraph.

Intuitively it is clear (if I am not mistaken) that every point will cut down the dimension of the linear system precisely by one (a point on a curve is one extra equation). I would like to see an exact statement in this direction (reference or a proof) and generalization if any.

Any help will be appreciated.